# Looking for a compendium of the constructions of universal algebra (and its generalizations)

Tags: reference-request, universal-algebra

Universal Algebra is interesting because it shows that the meta-theory of many algebras is in some very formal sense uniform, leading to precise theorems.

But there is another part to Universal Algebra, always present in all expositions, but that gets less light: the many constructions it enables.  For example, what a homomorphism is, and what a term algebra is, is a **construction**, not something that merely *exists* via some classical reasoning (i.e. using choice or excluded middle). There are, it turns out, many constructions.

What I'm looking for is a list of these, that both names them and defines them carefully. [The reason this can't easily be found in most textbooks is obvious: that is an eminently non-pedagogical mode of presentation. Such a list is an act of classification, not pedagogy. Of course, it is also ironic that this isn't the case, since Universal Algebra itself is a giant act of classification!]

Of course, I would be even happier to see **constructions** that work in multi-sorted quasi-equational algebras. But that part might actually be for MathOverflow.

Comment: If I were posting this question on MO, I might have marked it as 'Community Wiki', as it might be possible to accumulate a list of answers, rather than have a single best one.

Comment: The option to mark a question as 'Community Wiki' exists on MSE aswell. Just flag your post with 'in need of moderation intervention' and state it.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "constructions" of universal algebra.  When you ask for a compendium, it seems you might be seeking an "atlas" of concrete algebraic (or relational) structures [(such things exist)](https://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/finitestructures.html).  But you also refer to homomorphisms and term algebras as the "constructions" that interest you... so I'm confused. Is it a list of all the definitions of basic objects used in universal algebra that you seek?  Or maybe you want concrete examples of these objects?

Comment: @WilliamDeMeo I knew about Jipsen's list. I don't want structures, I want the structure-polymorphic terminating functions that apply to structures. Like homomorphism, term algebra, kernel, cokernel, etc.